dynamic url router express nodejs
So i wanna implement a router of path with a wildcard :guild for my website, however it doesnt work, I mean the code seems to completely not see the router. All other pages work, only the one with router doesnt
It would normally send Cannot GET ... but i prevent that so im getting redirected to "/".
This is app.js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const { secret } = require('./src/config/express/secret.json');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'src/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/assets', express.static('src/assets'));
app.use(
    session({
        secret: secret,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            secure: false,
            httpOnly: true,
        }
    })
);

const routes = {
    auth: {
        login: {
            path: '/auth/login',
            file: require('./src/routes/auth/login.js')
        },

        postLogin: {
            path: '/auth/post-login',
            file: require('./src/routes/auth/post-login.js')
        },

        logout: {
            path: '/auth/logout',
            file: require('./src/routes/auth/logout.js')
        }
    },
    dashboard: {
        servers: {
            path: '/dashboard/servers',
            file: require('./src/routes/dashboard/servers.js')
        },

        overview: {
            path: '/dashboard/server/:guild/overview',
            file: require('./src/routes/dashboard/overview.js')
        }
    },
    external: {
        discord: {
            path: '/discord',
            file: require('./src/routes/external/discord.js')
        }
    },
    static: {
        homepage: {
            path: '/',
            file: require('./src/routes/static/homepage.js')
        }
    },
}

for (const category in routes) {
    for (const route in routes[category]) {
        const routeConfig = routes[category][route];
        if (routeConfig.path && routeConfig.file) {
            app.get(routeConfig.path, routeConfig.file);
        }
    }
}

app.use('*', (req, res) => res.redirect('/'));

app.listen('8000', () => console.log('Listening to PORT 8000'));

And this is router file for now:
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/dashboard/server/:guild/overview', async (req, res) => {
    const { guild } = req.params;
    res.render('pages/dashboard/overview', {
        guild: guild;
    });
});

module.exports = router;


Where are you including the router you created in your main app.js file?

You're using app.get() for each path, and alas it doesn’t delegate routing to the individual route modules. So the actual router configurations inside the modules are overlooked. Hence, no dynamic nested routes for you.
for (const category in routes) {
    for (const route in routes[category]) {
        const routeConfig = routes[category][route];
        if (routeConfig.path && routeConfig.file) {
            app.get(routeConfig.path, routeConfig.file);
        }
    }
}

should be changed to:
for (const category in routes) {
    for (const route in routes[category]) {
        const routeConfig = routes[category][route];
        if (routeConfig.path && routeConfig.file) {
            app.use(routeConfig.path, routeConfig.file);
        }
    }
}

Then in your router you should have something like this:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:guild/overview', async (req, res) => {
    const { guild } = req.params;
    res.render('pages/dashboard/overview', {
        guild: guild,
    });
});

module.exports = router;

